# How to get background height after window resize with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

How can I get the background height after the window resized?

```css
div {
    background-image: url(/images/somebackground.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 90%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 70%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to get the window height after it resized.

You don't need to use jQuery for that:

```
// Event listener
window.addEventListener('resize', () => { // arrow function
    /* code to be executed after window was resized,
    you can get the height with window.innerHeight */
});
```

If you really want to use jQuery use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

[window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)

([Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

Hope that helped.